# Nodejs oracle Db connection on Openshift platform

Tags: node.js, oracle, kubernetes, openshift

I have created and deployed node.js application on Openshift platform.
I need to connect to oracle db which is on a remote host.
I am able to connect to the oracle Db from my local machine as i have installed oracle client.
But when I deploy the application to Openshift platform I get below error.

```
Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so
```

I know I need Oracle client installed on the hosting system.. but the openshift platform doesn't allow me any installation.

Can anybody suggest me any way how to get around this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you deploy a Docker container?  If so, then check out  https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleLinuxDevelopers/oraclelinux7/nodejs/12-oracledb/Dockerfile. Also see the node-oracledb installation instructions for docker: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#docker. And see the blog post series https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1